# Core Data Entity Search Using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that saves data to a Core Data sql then view it in a `tableView`. And I'm trying to add a `searchBar` to search through the data.

I created two `NSFetchedResultsController`. One for getting entity data and the other for getting entity data after filtering using `NSPredicate`.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack DefaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"offer" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedSearchResultsController{
    if (_fetchedSearchResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedSearchResultsController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack DefaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"offer" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];    

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"location contains[c] %@", self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    _fetchedSearchResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedSearchResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedSearchResultsController;
}
```

And showing data in each cell by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];//] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    Entry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Entry *searchEntry = [self.fetchedSearchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *recipe = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = searchEntry.location;
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = entry.location;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But I get this error: *'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'*

When I comment **[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];** out, I don't get the error anymore. So I'm assuming the error is coming from predicate but I don't know how to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

Entry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Entry *searchEntry = [self.fetchedSearchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
first check for entry and searchEntry wether returning null or not ?

Comment: I checked. I found that searchEntry is returning null.

Comment: thats why you are facing this error.Now check _fetchedSearchResultsController value wether nil or not in - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedSearchResultsController{

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I was checking searchEntry the wrong way. Now what I did is `NSLog(@"Checking searchEntry");
    if ([searchEntry isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
        NSLog(@"searchEntry is null");
    }` I got no logs.

Comment: Dear just add NSLog(@"search entry is %@", searchEntry);
and check the value for searchEntry